# Hide and change function not working on explore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote some code. The codes working on chrome, safari and mozilla but the codes not working on explorer.

```
$('#vize-islem').hide();
$('#vize-bilgi').hide();
$('#vize-ulke').on('change', function(e) {
    let self = $(e.target);
    self.next('a').attr('href', self.find(':selected').data('url')).html('<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>' + self.find(':selected').text());
    $('#vize-islem').hide();
    $('#vize-bilgi').hide();
    $.get('vize/vizeislem/' + self.val(), function(result) {
        $('#vize-islem option').remove();
        $('#vize-islem').append('<option value="">Seçiniz</option>');
        if ( result.length > 0 ) {
            $('#vize-islem').show('slow');
            for (let key in result) {
                let kategori = result[key];
                console.log(kategori);
                $('#vize-islem').append(`<option value="${kategori.id}" data-url="${kategori.url}">${kategori.title}</option>`);
            }
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

I want to hide and change on explorer.

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_". What you want your code to do, and what it does instead? Notice, that you've written ES6 code, trying to run it in a ES5 browser is not going to work.

Comment: Also please identify IE version(s) you tried.

Comment: `let` is probably the issue.  [Can I Use let?](https://caniuse.com/#search=let)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are completely unsupported in any version of IE. Similarly, the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword only works in IE11. You need to use `var` and string concatenation instead.

Also note that you should cache repeated selectors in your logic to improve performance. Try this:

```js
var $vize_islem = $('#vize-islem').hide();
var $vize_bilgi = $('#vize-bilgi').hide();

$('#vize-ulke').on('change', function(e) {
  let $self = $(e.target);
  $self.next('a').attr('href', $self.find(':selected').data('url')).html('<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>' + $self.find(':selected').text());
  $vize_islem.hide();
  $vize_bilgi.hide();

  $.get('vize/vizeislem/' + $self.val(), function(result) {
    $vize_islem.find('option').remove();
    $vize_islem.append('<option value="">Seçiniz</option>');

    if (result.length > 0) {
      $vize_islem.show('slow');
      for (let key in result) {
        let kategori = result[key];
        $vize_islem.append('<option value="' + kategori.id + '" data-url="' + kategori.url + '">' + kategori.title + '</option>');
      }
    }
  }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my solution :)  But I had some problem. I could'nt fix this problem. I did this but It's not working well.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix this part. For android browser and ie 10 <

```
$('#vizeislemler').on('change', function(e) {
    let $self = $(e.target);$self.next('a').attr('href', $self.find(':selected').data('url')).html('<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>' + $self.find(':selected').text());
    window.location = selected.data('url');
  });

  $('a[href*="#"]')
    // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function(event) {
        // On-page links
        if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
            && 
            location.hostname == this.hostname
        ) {
        // Figure out element to scroll to
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        // Does a scroll target exist?
        if (target.length) {
          // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
          event.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000, function() {
            // Callback after animation
            // Must change focus!
            var $target = $(target);
            //$target.focus();
            if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
              return false;
            } else {
              $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
              //$target.focus(); // Set focus again
            };
          });
        }
        }
      });
});
```